# Is conditional probability applicable to two different trials?

Tags: probability

I have a doubt that does conditional probability applies to the same trial only or can be applied to different trials.I have read a formula P(A/B)=P(A^B)/P(B) but I think this will work only when we are dealing with same trial.For example my book says that drawing a red card in second trial after the same event occurred in first trial is a example of conditional probability(=25/51) But I couldn't relate it to the above formula.

Comment: Why wouldn't it relate?  If $A$ is the event "the second card is red" and $B$ is the event "the first card is red" the formula holds perfectly.

Comment: Go back to the basic definitions for probability as to what a sample space is defined as and what an outcome is defined as.  Here we can consider the *combined result* of the first two (*or more than that if we cared*) results of drawing a card.  With 52 cards, there are $52\times 51$ different ways in which the two cards could be pulled out in sequence.  We can think of the combined action of drawing two cards as the *one trial* if you so insist and the formula then continues to make sense and hold perfectly well.

Comment: While, yes, it is helpful to think of $Pr(A)$ as $\frac{1}{2}$ or as $\frac{26}{52}$, it could just as easily have been thought of as $\frac{26\times 51}{52\times 51}$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment by @lulu:-

$p(B)=\frac{1}{4}$, $p(A|B)=\frac{12}{51}$, $p(A\cap B)=\frac{\begin{pmatrix}13\\2\\\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}52\\2\\\end{pmatrix}}$.

These will satisfy the rule you know which applies to **any** two events.